# WebStorm to autocomplete Mongoose schema fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, webstorm, mongoose-schema

Let's say I'm using the standard Mongoose model:

Creating a schema

```
const userSchema    = new mongoose.Schema({
  displayName     : {type: String, required: true},
  phoneNumber     : {type: String},
});
```

Then connect it to a model:

```
const UserModel = mongooseClient.model('User', userSchema);
```

I'd like WebStorm to autocomplete me in the following way:

```
const myUser = new UserModel();
myUser.disp // should suggest 'displayName'
```

How do I accomplish it?

Comment: try hitting ctrl+space after entering  myUser.

Comment: @Srinivas model is not object of schema, model is generated on runtime from schema, and WebStorm cannot resolve it

Comment: @num8er you are wrong. why? because as a human I can always understand that userModel will have the fields 'displayName' and 'phoneNumber'. So Webstorm can understand it too.

Comment: @YardenST You cannot understand the issue. **WebStorm** is **not a human**. When we call: `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)` that method generates mongoose model object. It happens on runtime. Which means that WS must execute that js file to have dump of object in memory. Seems like You've not worked with mongoose. If You've a solution, then write an answer to question I really need that stuff too.

Comment: @YardenST `because as a human I can always understand that userModel will have the fields 'displayName' and 'phoneNumber'. So Webstorm can understand it too`  **develop neural interface plugin for WebStorm then I'll agree Your comment**

Comment: I agree with @num8er the only way is to use JsDoc, create a type for the schema and mark the object when you add it as your type, webstorm will understand it then

Comment: + it can be achieved by using DDD, when You've entities and repositories You can work with entities as simple objects and then pass them to repository method to save update and etc. it takes a patience to write lots of code to abstract and etc...

Comment: @num8er writing a solution is not hard for my case at least. But I pay for Jetbrains so I prefer they will do it. Anyhow - regarding your comments, I don't agree, when I said human I meant: the steps are clear to me to understand what are the possible fields. so I can train a program to "understand" it too

Comment: @YardenST I do respect Your comments. I also pay for toolset of JetBrains. I hope they are already working on it. Just to be clear, training program to understand code habits is extra work. Time is money and I'll not work on plugin that will map objects to some schema and inject to intellisense logic. The talk was about doing minimal manipulations to achieve intellisense on objects.

Comment: @num8er I agree. for now I'm adding JSdoc as Iena suggested

Answer (score 4):

Providing completion for your schema fields/methods requires adding special support for Mongooze, as objects generated in runtime can't be resolved by static code analysis. We have a feature request for this, please feel free to vote: [WEB-22317](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22317).

For now, using JSDoc to annotate objects is the only way to go